# Install the latest build of Indy 10 on Lazarus

Tags: indy, lazarus

Is there a step-by-step guide about how to install the Indy 10 components in Lazarus?

I have checked out the last snv snapshot at https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10
Username: Indy-Public-RO
(No password)

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried: [Indy 10 Lazarus/FreePascal Port](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/fpc/index.en.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, the svn version contain FreePascal Port (in the Branch Folder). I don't know how to compile it on Windows.

Thank you Michal

Comment: There is readme.txt. I compiled it with 'make all' then 'make install'. Use make from FPC bin catalog.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki contains step by step installation instructions for Windows and Debian/Ubuntu :

[INDY with Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Indy_with_Lazarus)

I'm currently trying to get it to work on OSX.

Comment: It's referred to an old version. It doesn't work with svn version.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the commands in Wiki and now I have tons of components running under Ubuntu/Lazarus.